# Change binding source of a gridviewitem

Tags: c#, binding, grid, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `GridView` of which the `ItemsSource` is binded to a list of `StreamCollections`. In the `ItemsTemplateSelector`, I change the `DataTemplate` depending on value of that `StreamCollection`.

```
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null && item is StreamCollection)
    {
        StreamCollection stream = (StreamCollection) item;
        if (stream.Playlist != null)
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["PlaylistDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (stream.Track != null)
        {               
            return Application.Current.Resources["TrackDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If the `Playlist` is not `null`, the `GridViewItem` should have as binding the `Playlist`; same for `Track`. The `FrameworkElement` element is of type `GridViewItem` but I can't seem to find any reference to the `BindingSource`.

Comment: What's the XAML code ?
Can you try without the template selector, just to be sure that your XAML code and binding is ok for one of the element type (track for example) ?

Comment: Binding works for the element Track, and for Playlists. But in my List there can be 2 different types, either a track or a playlist. That's why I make a GridView which is binded to StreamCollection (which contains a property track and playlist)

Comment: I understand that the binding of your list and list elements is not working when using the TemplateSelector. So can you please try without using it to check if the problem is really here. Or elaborate your problem if that's not your problem ?

Comment: Please post xaml code

Comment: I've tested your posted code, it works fine by my side, but I'm curious what is your `StreamCollection`, I consider this as the the data model class of your `GridView`, and inside there are two properties `Playlist` and `Track`, what are the data type of these two properties? When I tried to reproduce your problem, I set these two properties as `List<string>`. Where did your put your two `DataTemplate`s? When you use `Application` resource, you can put them into the App.xaml file. If there still problems, please post your xaml code and data model.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure can it help or not, but when I have similar needs I have removed dictionary from application:

```
 App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Last());
```

And have add new one

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:AppStyle1.xaml");
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

So, you can try to put your template in dictionary and replace it this way